# Creating multiple users at once using Form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to give the ability to my user to create a team and create 3 users in one time that will populate that team.

Could you please help me to figure out why it is not working please?

forms.py  :

```
class InviteForm(forms.Form):
    Email1 = forms.EmailField()
    Email2 = forms.EmailField()
    Email3 = forms.EmailField()
```

Views.py

```
def TeamRegisterTest(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = InviteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user=[]
            for i in form:
                mail = i.value()
                user = MyUser(email = mail)
                user = user_create.save(commit=False)
                password = MyUser.objects.make_random_password()
                user.set_password(password)
                user.is_active = False
                user.is_employee = True
                user.save()
                u1 = user.id
                a1 = MyUser.objects.get(email = request.user.email)
                a2 = Project.objects.filter(project_hr_admin = a1)
                a3 = a2.latest('id')
                a4 = a3.team_id
                a4.members.add(u1)
                current_site = get_current_site(request)
                message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
                    'user':user,
                    'domain':current_site.domain,
                    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
                })
                mail_subject = 'You have been invited to SoftScores.com please sign in to get access to the app'
                to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
                email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
                email.send()
                return HttpResponse('An email have been sent to your user asking him to sign in')
        else:
            print("The entered form is not valid")

    else:
        form = InviteForm()
    return render(request,'team_register.html', {'form':form})
```

views.py (edited)

```
def TeamRegisterTest(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = InviteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            for i in form:
                mail = i.value()
                user = MyUser(email = mail)
                password = MyUser.objects.make_random_password()
                user.set_password(password)
                user.is_active = False
                user.is_employee = True
                user.save()
                u1 = user.id
                a1 = MyUser.objects.get(email = request.user.email)
                a2 = Project.objects.filter(project_hr_admin = a1)
                a3 = a2.latest('id')
                a4 = a3.team_id
                a4.members.add(u1)
                current_site = get_current_site(request)
                message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
                    'user':user,
                    'domain':current_site.domain,
                    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
                })
                mail_subject = 'You have been invited to SoftScores.com please sign in to get access to the app'
                to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
                email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
                email.send()
            return HttpResponse('An email have been sent to each Team member asking them to join in')
        else:
            print("The entered form is not valid")

    else:
        form = InviteForm()
    return render(request,'team_register.html', {'form':form})
```

I get a save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit', I guess that it is because commit is only for ModelsForm how can I save without commiting in order to continue to edit attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create instance of your model class without saving and change its attributes.

```
def TeamRegisterTest(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = InviteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            for i in form:
                mail = i.value()
                user = MyUser(email = mail)
                password = MyUser.objects.make_random_password()
                user.set_password(password)
                user.is_active = False
                user.is_employee = True
                user.save()
                # etc.
         else:
            print("The entered form is not valid")

    else:
        form = InviteForm()
    return render(request,'team_register.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: I get what you mean .. but I am not sure that bulk creating is the best way for me because actually my code more longer, have a look I edited the complete code

Comment: you can call save for your user object without bulk, I just added bulk because it'll work faster because you make 1 query

Comment: With updated question it will not work because you use created user in many-to-many field that mean that you must save user before adding it to many-to-many. You can change you algorithm or call save after you made all necessary actions with user in loop that can slow down your app.

Comment: I tried with the code views.py (edited) but it create only one user on the supposed three  and kind of stop at user.save() not executing the rest ..

Comment: Because you return `HttpResponse` in for loop it iterate only over first user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154770/discussion-between-ben2pop-and-dima-kudosh).

Answer (score 0):

by this row you create and save `MyUser`

```
user_create = MyUser.objects.create(email = mail)
```

and now `user_create` it is model instance and it save method does not have kwargs `commit` so you next line is extra just remove it:

```
user = user_create.save(commit=False)
```

Comment: Thx men for your answer as well ;)